# How to do math function on Asp Label Text?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried the small math into my asp label Text and it's not working.

```
<asp:Label ID="financial_year_edit_value" runat="server" CssClass="blueLabelStyle" Text='<%# (Convert.ToInt16("Last_Renewed_Year") + Convert.ToInt16(1) %>'></asp:Label>.
```

`Last_Renewed_Year` is a databinding object.

Can anybody please explain how to achieve the result by using the above math function. I just want to add `1` to the `Last_Renewed_Year` value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: web forms or asp.net-mvc?? what have you tried??

Comment: Can you give a little more context ? What is the type of "Last_Renewd_Year" ? Are you using databinding or Last_Renewed_Year is a property in your code behind ?

Comment: Hi, Last_Renewed_year is the Databinding and it's an web forms. It doesn't give any errors not displaying anything. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<%# (int)Eval("Last_Renewed_Year") + 1 %>`

Comment: I changed as per your answer `<asp:Label ID="financial_year_edit_value" runat="server" CssClass="blueLabelStyle" Text='<%# (int)Eval("Last_Renewed_Year") + 1 %>' ></asp:Label>` and I got this error: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: You have to use this label in the context of a databound control, e.g., a template column in Repeater or Gridview.

Comment: It is in the template column and the following is working fine. `'<%# Eval("Last_Renewed_Year")%>'`. Is any other way to get this? Thanks